# Notepad++ can't display Chinese Characters after updating to Windows 10 18363.592

Tags: character-encoding, windows-10, notepad++, windows-10-universal, windows-update

I just updated my windows 10 from `1909 18363.535` to `1909 18363.592`. Notepad++ used to work properly and was able to display Chinese Characters, but after this update
[image]

NONE of the Chinese character can be displayed. Initially, I thought it was a `Notepad++` problem, as it happened on my other laptop, so I copied the same file to my 2nd laptop which had the `18363.535` version, same version of Notepad++, the file was able to display just fine.

After the update, neither can display Chinese characters. I have even tried to change the file format, from `UTF8` to `ASCII` and checked some character encoding. None worked.
[image]
[image]

All Chinese are now squares. You can even input the new ones.

My locale was set correctly to Chinese on both computers using windows 10 X64 English (UK) version.
[image]

Anyone had the same/similar problems????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a long seach, as it turns out, it's a font problem.

[image]

Windows 10's lastest update somehow messed up the font.

Comment: how did you solve this problem? i have same problem. thanks

Comment: @roudan, you can configure the font through Settings-->Style Configurator, make sure the current font is correct.